# Navegador não exibe mais conteúdo após bloco php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Estou com um erro no meu código e já tentei procurar a solução mas não encontrei. Bom, basicamente quando eu tento fazer uma consulta sql, o navegador simplesmente não consegue interpretar o código php e não exibe mais nenhum conteúdo a partir do bloco php.´

**Código com o bloco php:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**E então o navegador não mostra mais nenhum conteúdo após o bloco php nem indica nenhum erro:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia colocar o código na pergunta de maneira textual?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Insere a linha abaixo no início do seu bloco php para ele mostar msgs de erro que podem estar ocorrendo

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ao colocar essa linha no bloco, é mostrado o erro que diz que a variável de conexão com o banco de dados não está definida, porém ainda sem solução, o arquivo em questão (este que mandei os prints na pergunta) está na 4° camada de pastas, e por algum motivo o arquivo de conexão não está pegando lá, está funcionando normalmente na 3° camada de pastas, ao verificar com o comando var_dump($pdo), é mostrando NULL como se a variável não existisse, mas quando insiro o mesmo comando em outros arquivos que estão na 3° camada de outras pastas, retorna normalmente a variável.

Comment: Bom, olhando direito o código, identifiquei exatamente o problema, basicamente, como estou usando uma função para incluir o arquivo em questão, a conexão com o banco de dados acaba não passando pra dentro da função e aí o arquivo não tem um valor para a variável. Então o problema foi resolvido.